SpringBoot3 @KafkaListener does not have traceId
Using Spring Boot 2 everything works properly, because sleuth does it.
But in SB3 sleuth is absent, and micrometer-tracing is used.
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

application.properties
spring.kafka.listener.observation-enabled=true
logging.pattern.console="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [${spring.application.name:-},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}] 0 --- [%15.80t] %-40.40logger{39} : %msg%n"

But logs does not have traceId spanId. How to fix it?

Here is a sample which does an observation for Spring AMQP: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-amqp-observation
Let's see if org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency does the trick!
I also remember that I had to add management.tracing.sampling.probability=1 into the application.properties for some reasons.
More info here in Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/actuator/tracing.html
